# error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I have a function with prototype `void* myFcn(void* arg)` which is used as the starting point for a pthread.  I need to convert the argument to an int for later use:

```
int x = (int)arg;
```

The compiler (GCC version 4.2.4) returns the error:

```
file.cpp:233: error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision
```

What is the proper way to cast this?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system?

Comment: You should be doing int x = *((int *)arg); You are casting from void * to int that is why you get the warning

Comment: I cannot reverse my upvote of user384706's answer, but it's wrong. `x = *((int *)arg);` is how you'd get an `int` /at the location pointed to by/ the `void*`. It does not reinterpret the `void*` itself as an `int`.

Comment: int *x = (int *)arg; // the value is *x

Comment: what if i needed the address of arg?

Answer (score 79):

You can cast it to an `intptr_t` type. It's an `int` type guaranteed to be big enough to contain a pointer. Use `#include <cstdint>` to define it.

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <stdint.h>` to get the `intptr_t` typedef.

Comment: `#include <inttypes.h>`. It includes stdint.h .

Comment: And if you really need an `int` (not just an integral type) you can do some simple bounds checking and then downcast the `intptr_t` to an `int`.

Answer (score 37):

Again, all of the answers above missed the point badly. The OP wanted to convert a pointer value to a int value, instead, most the answers, one way or the other, tried to wrongly convert the content of arg points to to a int value. And, most of these will not even work on gcc4.

The correct answer is, if one does not mind losing data precision,

```
int x = *((int*)(&arg));
```

This works on GCC4.

The best way is, if one can, do not do such casting, instead, if the same memory address has to be shared for pointer and int (e.g. for saving RAM), use union, and make sure, if the mem address is treated as an int only if you know it was last set as an int.

Comment: This method will not work on 64 bit Big Endian platform, so it unnecessarily breaks portability.

Comment: This is not even remotely "the correct answer". This is not a conversion at all. This is memory reinterpretation - a completely unacceptable way to do what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: This is flat out wrong. No idea how it amassed 27 upvotes?! -1

Comment: Uggh. Terrible solution. Wrong. This returns the first 32 bits of the pointer which may be the top or the bottom depending on big versus little endian, as comment #2 said. In the best case this will give the same results as the original code, with no advantages, but in the worst case it will fail in multiple catastrophic ways (type punning, endianness, less efficient, etc.)

Comment: @onlooker, this is simply a cast mechanism. It is not at all a right answer.

Comment: For those who are interested. I personally upvoted this answer because by it's first line of text it helped me to  understand the reason of this strange error message and what am I, poor idiot, doing :D

Answer (score 16):

Instead of:

```
int x = (int)arg;
```

use:

```
int x = (long)arg;
```

On most platforms pointers and longs are the same size, but ints and pointers often are not the same size on 64bit platforms.  If you convert (`void*`) to (`long`) no precision is lost, then by assigning the (`long`) to an (`int`), it properly truncates the number to fit.

Comment: Not valid on Windows 64 - long is still 32-bit but pointers are 64-bit.

Comment: That's not a good idea if the original object (that was cast to void*) was an integer. If the sizes are different then endianess comes into play.

Comment: @Martin York: No, it doesn't depend on endiannness. The mapping in pointer<->integer casts is implementation defined, but the intent was that if the pointer type is large enough and isn't forcefully aligned (`void*` doesn't) then round-trip cast integer-to-pointer-to-integer should produce the original value. Same for pointer-to-integer-to-pointer round trip.

Answer (score 13):

There's no proper way to cast this to `int` in general case. C99 standard library provides `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` typedefs, which are supposed to be used whenever the need to perform such a cast comes about. If your standard library (even if it is not C99) happens to provide these types - use them. If not, check the pointer size on your platform, define these typedefs accordingly yourself and use them.

Answer (score 8):

Casting a pointer to void* and back is valid use of reinterpret_cast<>. So you could do this:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myFcn, new int(5)); // implicit cast to void* from int*
```

Then in myFcn:

```
void* myFcn(void* arg)
{
    int*  data = reinterpret_cast<int*>(arg);
    int   x    = *data;
    delete data;
```

Note: As sbi points out this would require a change on the OP call to create the thread.

What I am trying to emphasis that conversion from int to pointer and back again can be frough with problems as you move from platform to platform. BUT converting a pointer to void* and back again is well supported (everywhere).

Thus as a result it may be less error prone to generate a pointer dynamcially and use that.
Remembering to delete the pointer after use so that we don't leak.

Comment: But that's different. From the question I presume the OP does `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myFcn, 5)`, which will make your idea fail.

Comment: What I am saying is that it would be safer to use new(5) rather than 5 and deal with it appropriately at the other end.

Comment: I understood, but that would introduce dynamic memory and ugly lifetime issues (an object allocated by one thread must be freed by some other) - all just to pass an `int` to a thread.

Comment: Even if there are issues with freeing the int in a thread (which there usually is not). Then loosing one int to memory management seems preferable to getting the wrong int at the other end.

Comment: Ugh. I strongly disagree. And casting an `int` to `void*` and back can only be a problem on a platform where `sizeof(int)>sizeof(void*)`. I'm not sure the standard even allows such platforms.

Comment: There is absolutely not gurantee that sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void*). Infact I know several systems where that does not hold.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for setting me straight on what the standard does (not) require regarding the size of built-ins. But which are those platforms? And do they implement Posix threads anyway?

Comment: Off the top of my head: KSR-64. Which supported 64 bit address space and 128 bit integers. (PS the 64 in KSR-64 is the number of processors not the address size :-) It ran a standard version of Unix (forget which veriant) that include pthread support. A lot of compilers also support using larger integers with just an extra flag.

Comment: @Martin: That's one, and it's one even google hasn't heard about. (Note that the C++ code written by me runs on half a dozen of different platforms - and that's only because I consider all Linux versions as a single platform -, so I'm not as Wintel-centric as many others.) Please be reasonable. There might even be platforms where you are not allowed to cast between `int*` and `void*`.

Comment: @sbi: Standard gurantees that casting any pointer to void* and back again will result in a valid value. As for KSR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_Square_Research  Also even gcc can support 128 bit integers:http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-09/msg00416.html

Comment: @SBI: At my last company I was responcable for building ACE/TAO across 32 different platfrom configuration (Hardware/OS/Compiler) and for each configuration we had 8 different build types (Debug-release/Single-Multi Thread/Shared-Static lib) I did not have the luxary of assuming that anything would work unless it was explicitly stated in the standard and even then there are some gotchas.

Comment: @sbi. Your method will work on most user desktops for the next 3-5 years or so. But will eventually fail. My method is guranteed to work by the standard.

Comment: @sbi: even if casting int to void* works, imaging now having to pass 2 ints to a thread, or a string? are int's so special? (obviously, they're special enough for some to provide an intptr_t type)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a `long` cast, you should cast to `size_t`.

```
int val= (int)((size_t)arg);
```

Answer (score 4):

Safest way :

```
static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<long>(void * your_variable));
```

`long` guarantees a pointer size on Linux on any machine. Windows has 32 bit long only on 64 bit as well. Therefore, you need to change it to `long long` instead of `long` in windows for 64 bits.
So `reinterpret_cast` has casted it to `long` type and then `static_cast` safely casts `long` to `int`, if you are ready do truncte the data.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to cast it to another `pointer type`. Converting a `void*` to an `int` is non-portable way that may work or may not! If you need to keep the returned address, just keep it as `void*`.

Comment: The point is (probably) that the value passed to the thread is an integer value, not really a 'void *'.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I was thinking about my answer in another thread:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593580/c-how-to-get-the-address-stored-in-a-void-pointer/1593588#1593588

Comment: AraK is correct, passing integers a pointers are not necessarily interchangeable. He should pass the address of the integer, the thread should get that address, `static_cast` it to an `int*`, then get the value. This must be done before the integer goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" way to store a 64-bit pointer in an 32-bit integer. The problem is not with casting, but with the target type loosing half of the pointer. The 32 remaining bits stored inside `int` are insufficient to reconstruct a pointer to the thread function. Most answers just try to extract 32 useless bits out of the argument.

As [Ferruccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086/ferruccio) said, int must be replaced with `intptr_t` to make the program meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your thread creation function like this

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myFcn, reinterpret_cast<void*>(5));
```

then the `void*` arriving inside of `myFcn` has the value of the `int` you put into it. So you know you can cast it back like this

```
int myData = reinterpret_cast<int>(arg);
```

even though the compiler doesn't know you only ever pass `myFcn` to `pthread_create` in conjunction with an integer.

*Edit*:

As was pointed out by Martin, this presumes that `sizeof(void*)>=sizeof(int)`. If your code has the chance to ever be ported to some platform where this doesn't hold, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a structure and pass that as void* to pthread_create

```
struct threadArg {
    int intData;
    long longData;
    etc...
};


threadArg thrArg;
thrArg.intData = 4;
...
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myFcn, (void*)(threadArg*)&thrArg);


void* myFcn(void* arg)
{
    threadArg* pThrArg = (threadArg*)arg;
    int computeSomething = pThrArg->intData;
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that *thrArg* should exist till the *myFcn()* uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass your int as a `void*`, pass a `int*` to your `int`, so you can cast the `void*` to an `int*` and copy the dereferenced pointer to your `int`.

```
int x = *static_cast<int*>(arg);
```

Comment: If you do this, you have the thread reference a value that (hopefully still) lives in some other thread. That could create all kinds of trouble.

Comment: pthread passes the argument as a void*. This is an old C callback mechanism so you can't change that. And you can't pass a pointer to a stack based object from the other thread as it may no longer be valid.

Comment: There are ways to prevent this: pass a dynamic allocated argument if your not the passing thread is not static or if your argument is a local variable, otherwise there is no issue.

Comment: I agree passing a dynamically allocated pointer is fine (and I think the best way). But you seem to suggest by your answer that the user can pass 5 to pthread_create and then perform the above cast to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is

```
int x = reinterpret_cast<int>(arg);
```

This allows you to reinterpret the `void *` as an `int`.

Comment: Note: This is only appropriate is you cast the `int` to a `void *` in the first place.

Comment: @Artelius: Which, presumably, is exactly what Joshua did: `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myFcn, reinterpret_cast<void*>(5));`.

Comment: A C++ reinterpret cast will not solve the problem.  If the original type is a void *, converting to an int may lose date on platforms where sizeof(void *) != sizeof(int) (which is true of LP64 programming model).

Comment: Hmm? As long as `sizeof(void *) > sizeof(int)`, there is no problem, seeing as you first cast from `int` to `void *` and then back again.

Answer (score 0):

```
//new_fd is a int
pthread_create(&threads[threads_in_use] , NULL, accept_request, (void*)((long)new_fd));

//inside the method I then have
int client;
client = (long)new_fd;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a 32-bit value that needed to be passed to an OpenGL function as a void * representing an offset into a buffer.

You cannot just cast the 32-bit variable to a pointer, because that pointer on a 64-bit machine is twice as long.  Half your pointer will be garbage.  You need to pass an actual pointer.

This will get you a pointer from a 32 bit offset:

```
int32 nOffset   = 762;       // random offset
char * pOffset  = NULL;      // pointer to hold offset
pOffset         += nOffset;  // this will now hold the value of 762 correctly
glVertexAttribPointer(binding, nStep, glType, glTrueFalse, VertSize(), pOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer is incompatible to void* (and any other non function pointer)

Answer (score -3):

Well it does this because you are converting a 64 bits pointer to an 32 bits integer so you loose information.

You can use a 64 bits integer instead howerver I usually use a function with the right prototype and I cast the function type :
eg.

```
void thread_func(int arg){
...
}
```

and I create the thread like this :

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))thread_func, (void*)arg);
```

Comment: If the function had the correct signature you would not need to cast it explicitly.

Comment: But then you need to cast your arguments inside your thread function which is quite unsafe ... cf. this question

Comment: You think by casting it here that you are avoiding the problem! You are just making it bigger by tricking the compiler and the ABI.

Comment: Casting arguments inside the function is a lot safer. What you do here is undefined behavior, and undefined behavior of very practical sort.

Comment: this way I convert an int to a void* which is much better than converting a void* to an int. I don't see how anything bad can happen . Please tell me ...

Comment: @Ben. You are not converting anything to anything. You are messing around with the function type not the parameter type. You are delibrately subverting the compilers ability to tell the real type of the function. It still passes a void* to your function no conversion is done it places the bit pattern of a void* on the stack. Your function treats the bit pattern on the stack as if it is an integer.

Comment: @Ben: Your `thread_func` is called with a `void*`, which it interprets as an `int`. So you still convert (and how could you avoid it?), only it's done with function parameters on the stack. That's probably less safe than the explicit cast. Plus you cheated with function pointer types. Yuck.