# How do I work around the GCC "error: cast from ‘SourceLocation*’ to ‘int’ loses precision" error when compiling cmockery.c?

Tags: gcc, casting, compilation, cmockery

I need to add unit tests using [Cmockery](http://code.google.com/p/cmockery/) to an existing build environment that uses as hand-crafted Makefile.  So I need to figure out how to build cmockery.c (without automake).

When I run:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DPIC -I ../cmockery-0.1.2 -I /usr/include/malloc -c ../cmockery-0.1.2/cmockery.c -o obj/cmockery.o
```

I get a long list of errors like this:

```
../cmockery-0.1.2/cmockery.c: In function ‘void initialize_source_location(SourceLocation*)’:
../cmockery-0.1.2/cmockery.c:248: error: cast from ‘SourceLocation*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
```

Here are lines 247:248 of cmockery.c:

```
static void initialize_source_location(SourceLocation * const location) {
    assert_true(location);
```

`assert_true` is defined on line 154 of cmockery.h:

```
#define assert_true(c) _assert_true((int)(c), #c, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

So the problem (as the error states) is GCC doesn't like the cast from ‘SourceLocation*’ to ‘int’.

I can build Cmockery using `./configure` and `make` (on Linux, and [on Mac OS X](http://groups.google.com/group/cmockery/browse_thread/thread/046ac9d8189760a4#) if I `export CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/malloc` first), without any errors.  I've tried looking at the command-line that compiles cmockery.c when I run `make` (after `./configure`):

```
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./src -I./src -Isrc/google -I/usr/include/malloc -MT libcmockery_la-cmockery.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcmockery_la-cmockery.Tpo -c src/cmockery.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libcmockery_la-cmockery.o
```

...but I don't see any options that might work around this error.

In "[error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision)", I see I could change `(int)` in cmockery.h to `(intptr_t)`.  And I've confirmed that works.  But since I can build Cmockery with `./configure` and `make`, there must be a way to get it to build without modifying the source.

Comment: Well, it's letting you know that pointers (64 nowadays) are bigger than ints (might be 32). I wonder if a double cast, or something like (int)(((long long) x) & 0x00000000ffffffff) would sufficiently trick it.

Comment: Have you tried using `gcc` instead of `g++`? Using `g++` does occasionally change some things wrt the language.

Comment: David, changing the cast to (intptr_t) works, but I shouldn't have to modify the Cmockery source.

Comment: thkala, using gcc changes the errors to warnings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gcc` instead of `g++` on my system turns that error into a warning on my system (Mandriva Linux 2010.1 64-bit) and allows the compilation to complete:

```
.
.
.
../cmockery-0.1.2/cmockery.c:248: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
.
.
.
```

I feel the need to point out, however, that I am generally wary when I see a whole horde of warnings on what is a relatively common platform (Linux 64-bit/GCC and I would presume others). Using the `-m32` option to force compilation to a 32-bit object file does not produce any warnings, so one could presume that the source code used as-is is may not be 64-bit clean. This happens whether you use the autotools or not.

I don't know the project in question, so it might very well be OK, but in any case use with caution...

EDIT:

According to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/cmockery/msg/278ef41d988f24e1?hl=en) answer to the OP's question to the cmockery mailing list, the current release is not 64-bit clean at this time. It seems that the errors/warnings were there for a good reason...

Comment: Cmockery (as released) is not 64-bit clean: http://groups.google.com/group/cmockery/msg/278ef41d988f24e1?hl=en