# linux c-pthreads: problem with local variables

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

trying to calculate fibonacci's number with threads. It always return 1. Any suggestions?

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
/* compile with -lpthread */
void*  fibo (void* param) {
    int    a,b,n;
    pthread_t thread_a, thread_b;
    int ret;

    n = (int) param;
    if (n>1)
    {    pthread_create(&thread_a,NULL,fibo,(void*)(n-1));    
        pthread_create(&thread_b,NULL,fibo,(void*)(n-2));
        pthread_join(thread_a,(void**)&a);
        pthread_join(thread_b,(void**)&b);
        ret=a+b;
    }
    else    ret=1;
    return (ret);    
    /*pthread_exit((void**)ret);*/
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int n,ret;
    n=atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,fibo,(void*)n);
    pthread_join(thread_id,(void**)&ret);
    printf("s(%d)=%d\n",n,ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're probably on a 64-bit system.

Your problem is in the pthread_join:

```
int n,ret;
pthread_join(thread_id,(void**)&ret);
```

On 64-bit systems, `int`s are 32 bits, but `void*`s are 64 bits. So you're trying to store 64 bits in a 32-bit-wide variable. As as result, you overwrite other locations on the stack and just generally make a huge mess of things. Make sure to retrieve the value into a true `void *` and things ought to work better. Better yet, use the `void*` pointer as a true pointer; for example, you could pass a pointer to an `int` as the thread function argument, and use that as the argument, then write the result to the same location.

Incidentally, GCC warns about this, even without any warning switches:

```
test.c:30: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

Please don't ignore these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error:

```
n = (int) param;
```

whereas **param** is an **void***. so, you convert a pointer to an **int**, which is likely yilds a negative number, and the control passes to the **else** branch :)

**EDIT:** but there still may be a caveat here: [error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision)

Answer (score 0):

Threads do not use the same local variables, since local variables are on the stack, and each thread has its own stack. Threads *do* share global variables unless they are made explicitly thread-local.

You can create thread-local storage in pthreads using [pthread_key_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html) and related functions.

(as vines points out, this is beside the point as your error is not really thread-related)