# How create a simple program using threads in C?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, fedora

I'm new in C development, I know just the basics and I need to create a program that discover a simple hash password like this one:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_HASH 256
#define SIZE_PASSWORD 4

/* Get the hash from a passwod and put the result in hash. The array hash shoud have at lest 14 elements. */
void calculate_hash_password(const char *password, char *hash);

void increment_password(char *password);
void test_password(const char *p_hash, const char *password);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  char password[SIZE_PASSWORD + 1];

  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Use: %s <hash>", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE_PASSWORD; i++) {
    password[i] = 'a';
  }
  password[SIZE_PASSWORD] = '\0';

  while (1) {
    test_password(argv[1], password);
    increment_password(password);
  }
  return 0;
}

void test_password(const char *p_hash, const char *password) {
  char hash_calculado[SIZE_HASH + 1];

  calculate_hash_password(password, hash_calculado);
  if (!strcmp(p_hash, hash_calculado)) {
    printf("Achou! %s\n", password);
    exit(0);
  }
}

void increment_password(char *password) {
  int i;

  i = SIZE_PASSWORD - 1;
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (password[i] != 'z') {
      password[i]++;
      i = -2;
    } else {
      password[i] = 'a';
      i--;
    }
  }
  if (i == -1) {
    printf("Não achou!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}


void calculate_hash_password(const char *password, char *hash) {
  struct crypt_data data;
  data.initialized = 0;
  strcpy(hash, crypt_r(password, "aa", &data));
}
```

I must do the same thing as this one but using threads in C.
How can I do that ?

**EDIT**
[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using threads to hash passwords is not a particularly intuitive or obviously useful approach, so it is not clear *why* anyone would want to do that.

Presumably the calculation for hashing is split up in some way:  perhaps one thread processes passwords beginning with `A` through `M` and another does `N` through `Z`, or some such partitioning.  One idea would be to run the same function multiple times with a parameter which determines which partition to execute.  Here is a simple, functioning program which demonstrates the framework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>    

static void *calc_func (void *arg)
{                               
        int param = (int) arg;
        if (param == 1) 
        {
                // do first partition of calculation
                // ...  
                std::cout << "partition 1" << std::endl;
        }                       
        else            
        {
                // do second partition of calculation
                // ...  
                std::cout << "partition 2" << std::endl;
        }                       
}                               

int main (...)
{                       
        // ...          
        pthread_t threadh[2];

        if (pthread_create (&threadh[0], NULL, calc_func, (void *)1) != 0)
        {               
                std::cerr << "error creating thread 1" << std::endl;
        }                       

        if (pthread_create (&threadh[1], NULL, calc_func, (void *)2) != 0)
        {                               
                std::cerr << "error creating thread 2" << std::endl;
        }               
        // wait for threads to exit
        pthread_join (threadh[0], NULL);
        pthread_join (threadh[1], NULL);
        return 0;       
}
```

To build it on Linux using gcc, use the command `g++ -pthread filename.c++ -o filename`

Comment: I try to compile your code but gives an error. I update my post with the image of it so you can see it.

Comment: I solve the compile error change (int) arg to (long) arg, as is showed here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision

Comment: @Valter Henrique:  That's a strange error.  Try changing the `int` in that line to `long` (or maybe `long long`) to find a compatible size.

Comment: I did that mate, it works fine, the output was : partition 2 partition 1, that's right, right ? :)

Comment: I don't have to use some block ? like semaphore here @wallyk ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: Not for what I wrote.  They are not dependent on each other for anything, so no need for handshaking.  (I noticed the timing changed every time I ran it, sometimes showing `partition 1` on one line and `partition 2` on the other, sometimes they were on the same line followed by two newlines, and almost every time they alternated order of 1 and 2.)

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux shell execute:

```
man pthread_create
```

Read it carefully, and notice that provides a very descriptive example, on how to use threads. See also the man pages of the functions in the **SEE ALSO** section.

If you are on windows you can see the decomentation of pthreads-win32 [here](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/index.html)

After that you have to decide which part(s) of your code can be parallelized and assign that code to different threads.

Comment: I'm using Fedora, I will take a look in your suggestion