# Function , array and pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a situation where a function can only take "int" (can't change this) and I need it in a different situation. let me directly write the code

```
bool foo(int dev) 
{
         ...
         ...
      return true/false;
}
```

I need to pass :

1. `mClassPointer->dev()`
2. `mClassPointer[index]->dev()`
3. `dev() //(function)`
4. and obviously `dev //(variable)`

`mClassPointer` is pointer to class.
`dev()` is a member function of a class , return an Integer.

Comment: It is very unclear as to what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Thank You, Als for editing I am new here no much familiar with the syntax

Comment: You do not want to `return true/false;`.  Division by zero is undefined.

Comment: James , that's just to refer ture or false :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that needs to handle different datatypes in different situations (as is vaguely implied in your question), then perhaps you need to [look into templates.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: +1 for how to make the function really generic. I don't really know if that's what he meant or if there's some weird restriction that only allows him to accept integers.

Comment: Please elaborate I have a situation where I can take only "int" value

Comment: @SelectCall Could you elaborate as to your question? We're not sure what you want to do or why.

Comment: @SelectCall What other *types* do you want the function to take? Your question isn't clear enough there. Theoretically using a template can allow any type to be used... provided it doesn't break the code the template is used in

Comment: I have couple of device which I need to support , to validate the device I have been calling function at different places which takes above listed arguments . till now It has only "int" now as I am modifying further requires it to handle all 

I wanna make function generic

Comment: If you want to employ generic functions while staying strictly C++, then templates are a much safer bet over using a void*. I'd suggest you follow the link I provided and learn about them.

Comment: Alex, can we have other option to do the same thing or other proposal for new funcation?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean there...could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do that by changing the argument to a void*.

Be very careful with this and read this thread carefully, espc. the post by Loki Astari:

[error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision)

If the function only accepts an int then I don't know if this is possible. Read a discussion in this thread if you are thinking of casting your pointers to int and passing. May not work on certain platforms: [Converting a pointer into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer)

Comment: But he says, 'function can only take "int"'. I'm totally confused about what he's asking.

Comment: He wants to be able to pass multiple types to a function that takes an int?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that is possible without issues. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer

Comment: Oh, that seems issue if it does't then need to care anything else not disturb if I change the type?

Comment: @SelectCall not sure what you mean?

Comment: @SelectCall just out of curiosity, what is your native language?