# error: cast from ‘...’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, casting

In my code `Graph` is a class having a member `node`, which is a structure. When I do

```
unsigned int id  = ((unsigned int)n - (unsigned int)_nodes) / sizeof(Graph::node);
```

I get the following error (compiled on 64-bit Linux):

```
error: cast from ‘Graph::node* {aka Graph::node_st*}’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

Googled and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640423/error-cast-from-void-to-int-loses-precision) but it does not seem to me that the answer is applicable here (note that I want to get the size of the object but not itself).

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Why are you casting a pointer to `unsigned long`?

Comment: If both `n` and `_nodes` are pointers to `Graph::node`, and both are pointing into the same memory area, then you don't have to do any casting.

Comment: You're casting a 64 bit pointer to an `unsigned int` which is most likely 32 bits.

Comment: On (most) 64-bit Linuxes, pointers are 64-bits long and unsigned int is 32 bits long.  So the error message is exactly correct.

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks to 0x499602D2, Joachim, Jonathan and Tom for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` and `_nodes` point to `Graph::node`, i.e., they are of type `Graph::node *` (which seems to be the case from the error message), and *if* you wan to calculate the "distance" between the two in terms of the number of `Graph::node` elements, you can do:

```
unsigned int id = n - _nodes;
```

In C and C++, pointer arithmetic will result in the difference being the number of elements (instead of number of bytes).

For this to work portably, both `n` and `_nodes` must point to a contiguous block of `Graph::node` values, and `n` should be "after" `_nodes`.  If you can get negative differences, you can use `ptrdiff_t` type instead of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

The [first answer in the SO post you have a link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1640460/434551) provides an answer that should work for you.

Use

```
intptr_t id  = ((intptr_t)n - (intptr_t)_nodes) / sizeof(Graph::node);
```

Comment: Hi Sahu. Thanks for the answer. This solution works. However for my case I think @Alok's solution is more elegant.
+1